How to send MIMECONTENT using Graph SDK V5 (.NET)
Currently, I'm working on sending reserved mail system using graph sdk.
I'm trying to send saved .eml file(Mimecontent) using graph sdk (v5).
I found some way on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but it only show way for http.
Therefore, I'm using MIMEKIT library and reconstruct the email and send but I don't think this is a best way to do it.
byte[] newbuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(newbuffer)) {
    var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(memoryStream);
    var message = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message
    {
        Subject = mimeMessage.Subject,
        Body = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = mimeMessage.HtmlBody != null ? Microsoft.Graph.Models.BodyType.Html : Microsoft.Graph.Models.BodyType.Text,
            Content = mimeMessage.HtmlBody ?? mimeMessage.TextBody
        },
        ToRecipients = mimeMessage.To.Mailboxes.Select(mailbox => new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress { Address = mailbox.Address }
        }).ToList()
    };
    var draftMessage = await gsc.Users[userinfo.UserPrincipalName].Messages.PostAsync(message);
    foreach (var attachment in mimeMessage.Attachments.OfType<MimeKit.MimePart>())
    {
        var attachmentStream = new MemoryStream();
        attachment.Content.DecodeTo(attachmentStream);
        byte[] fileBytes = attachmentStream.ToArray(); 
        attachmentStream.Dispose(); 
        var fileAttachment = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.FileAttachment
        {
            OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            ContentBytes = fileBytes,
            ContentType = attachment.ContentType.MimeType,
            Name = attachment.FileName
        };
        await gsc.Users[userinfo.UserPrincipalName].Messages[draftMessage.Id].Attachments.PostAsync(fileAttachment);
    }
    await gsc.Users[userinfo.UserPrincipalName].Messages[draftMessage.Id].Send.PostAsync();
}

I'm wondering I may use ToPostRequestInformation for more simple way? Or anyone know the other way? please help me

I would use ToPostRequestInformation to create an request info and then set Content which should be a stream from .eml file
RequestInformation ri = gsc.Users[userinfo.UserPrincipalName].SendMail.ToPostRequestInformation(new SendMailPostRequestBody());
// set header
ri.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
ri.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");
// set input stream, content
ri.Content = new MemoryStream(newbuffer);

// get request adapter
var requestAdapter = graphClient.RequestAdapter;
var errorMapping = new Dictionary<string, ParsableFactory<IParsable>> {
    {"XXX", ODataError.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue},
};

// send request
await requestAdapter.SendNoContentAsync(ri, errorMapping);


hmm I'm getting error at await requestAdapter.SendNoContentAsync(ri);
Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.ApiException: The server returned an unexpected status code and no error factory is registered for this code: 400
Any possible reason for this?

@JohnPark I've update the code to add error mapping, but it will not resolve 400 Bad Request. I will try more .eml files to reproduce the issue.
